# Html5 canvas drawImage stretched

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I tried to draw image on html5 canvas . The issue is image stretched in canvas

```
load('img_the_scream',
    'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg',
    function( img ){
        console.log(  img.width , img.height );
        ctx.drawImage( img, 10, 10 , img.width , img.height );
    }
);
```

I added this issue in http://jsfiddle.net/75rAU/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is because you modified the canvas size in CSS.
The canvas has two separate size : The HTML size (the one you put inside the canvas tag) and the css size, which is actually a rescaling of the canvas.
The HTML size is the size you control (when you draw, it uses this size) and the CSS size is the displayed size which is a rescaling of the HTML size.

So here, your canvas has the default size (which I don't remember) but is resized (and stretched) by the css

HTML :

```
<canvas id="cv" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
```

CSS :

```
 #cv {
    background:#ff0;
}
```

Here I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75rAU/2/) with the correct size assignation

Answer (score 7):

Canvas has it's own sizes. `300x150` at default. Styles (width/height) just stretch `canvas` like any image. So, you should strongly set sizes to what you want. You may do it through html `<canvas width="123" height="123"></canvas>` or from JS code `canvas.width = canvas.height = 123`. Also, here you may set sizes by image properties `canvas.width = img.width` etc.

So, look at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/75rAU/3/
It works well

Little **upd**: http://jsfiddle.net/75rAU/4/ — this may help too